# Can't pass parameter of type CGColorRef in LLDB

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics, lldb, core-foundation

I'm extending Facebook’s [Chisel](https://github.com/facebook/chisel) to be able to visualize a color from the debugger. I want it to work for `UIColor`, `CIColor`, and `CGColorRef`. The two object-based ones are working fine, but the `CGColorRef` is giving me trouble.

[Here](https://github.com/facebook/chisel/issues/103) is the bug I'm working from, where I've already hashed out a bunch of the stuff from this question.

I've boiled the issue down to this test case:

If I have some function:

```
+ (UIColor *)someColor {
    UIColor *uiColor = [UIColor redColor];
    CGColorRef cgColor = uiColor.CGColor;
    UIColor *newUIColor = [UIColor colorWithCGColor:cgColor];
    return newUIColor;
}
```

And I set a breakpoint on the `return newUIColor;` line, this is what happens in LLDB:

```
(lldb) po cgColor
<CGColor 0x7f992b626710> [<CGColorSpace 0x7f992b70d5b0> (kCGColorSpaceDeviceRGB)] ( 0 0.478431 1 1 )

(lldb) po [UIColor colorWithCGColor:cgColor]
error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'CGColor *' with an lvalue of type 'CGColorRef' (aka 'CGColor *')
error: 1 errors parsing expression
(lldb) po [UIColor colorWithCGColor:(CGColorRef)cgColor]
error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'CGColor *' with an rvalue of type 'CGColorRef' (aka 'CGColor *')
error: 1 errors parsing expression
(lldb) po [UIColor colorWithCGColor:(id)cgColor]
error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'CGColor *' with an rvalue of type 'id'
error: 1 errors parsing expression
(lldb) po [UIColor colorWithCGColor:(CGColor *)cgColor]
error: use of undeclared identifier 'CGColor'
error: expected expression
error: 2 errors parsing expression
(lldb) expr @import CoreGraphics
(lldb) po [UIColor colorWithCGColor:(CGColorRef)cgColor]
error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'CGColor *' with an rvalue of type 'CGColorRef' (aka 'CGColor *')
error: 1 errors parsing expression
(lldb) po [UIColor colorWithCGColor:(CGColor *)cgColor]
error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'CGColor *' with an rvalue of type 'CGColor *'
error: 1 errors parsing expression
(lldb) po [UIColor colorWithCGColor:(struct CGColor *)cgColor]
error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'CGColor *' with an rvalue of type 'struct CGColor *'
error: 1 errors parsing expression
```

So, how can I get `lldb` to execute a line that takes a parameter of type `CGColorRef`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work using:

```
(lldb) po [[UIColor alloc] initWithCGColor:cgColor]
UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1
```

From `UIColor.h`:

```
@property(nonatomic,readonly) CGColorRef CGColor;
- (CGColorRef)CGColor NS_RETURNS_INNER_POINTER CF_RETURNS_NOT_RETAINED;
```

So I believe the `UIColor` is going out of scope and the memory of the `.CGColor` is no longer valid. I would probably have to copy it, but for my purposes, using the `-initWithCGColor:` works fine.